# Using Pykd with SOS

Tags: python, 64-bit, windbg, pykd

I wanted to do the following in PyKd: execute a command of another extension and process its output.

First of all, it seems I have to load SOS in PyKd, not in WinDbg. I did this with

```
>>> print(loadExt("C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\sos.dll"))
59323328
```

Next I wanted to perform a call on the extension like this:

```
>>> print(callExt(59323328, "!dumpheap -stat", ""))
```

(The third paramter is [not documented in API](https://pykd.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PYKD%200.2.%20API%20Reference&referringTitle=Documentation#callExt).)

However, it gives me the error

```
The call to LoadLibrary(C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\2.0.50727\sos.dll) failed
Win32 error 0n126
"The module could not be found."
Please check your debugger configuration and/or network access.
```

I'm doing all this within a `!pycmd` command prompt.

**How can I call SOS commands from PyKd and process the output?**

Versions:

> WinDbg 9.2.9200.16384 x64
>   debugging a 64 bit application
>   Pykd 0.2.0.26 64 bit
>   Python 2.7.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a python sugar:

> loadExt(**r**"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\sos.dll")

About output length [see the pykd issue tracker](https://pykd.codeplex.com/workitem/12653), I've posted a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Stupid mistake, I should escape paths like this:

```
>>> print(loadExt("C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework64\\v2.0.50727\\sos.dll"))
```